# can a textNode have a childNode which is an elementNode?

Tags: javascript, dom

Say,is the following possible:

```
textNode.appendChild(elementNode);
```

`elementNode` refers to those with `nodeType` set to 1

`textNode` refers to those with `nodeType` set to 2

It's not easy to produce.

The reason I ask this is that I find a function that adds a cite link to the end of a quotation:

```
function displayCitations() {
  var quotes = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");
  for (var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {
  if (!quotes[i].getAttribute("cite")) continue;
  var url = quotes[i].getAttribute("cite");
  var quoteChildren = quotes[i].getElementsByTagName('*');
  if (quoteChildren.length < 1) continue;
  var elem = quoteChildren[quoteChildren.length - 1];
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  var link_text = document.createTextNode("source");
  link.appendChild(link_text);
  link.setAttribute("href",url);
  var superscript = document.createElement("sup");
  superscript.appendChild(link);
  elem.appendChild(superscript);
  }
}
```

**see the last line "`elem.appendChild(superscript);`" where `elem` can be a `textNode`?**

I think the reason it's difficult to prove it because it's hard to get access to a specified `textNode`. Have anyone any way to achieve that?

Comment: No - in this example `elem` cannot be a textNode. the array `quoteChildren` is populated via HTMLElement.getElementsByTagName() which doesn't return text nodes. And `elem` is the last value in `quoteChildren`

Comment: Right,I've found my mistake.But the question still deserves a answer,right?Have you tried to append an elementNode to a textNode?

Comment: Yup, never had before but it was trivial to exercise. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, text nodes are always leafs.  Instead you must add new nodes to the text node's parent - making them siblings of the text node.

### EDIT

Here's an example where I attempt to add a child to a text node.

```
<div id="test">my only child is this text node</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var div = document.getElementById( 'test' );
var textNode = div.childNodes[0];
var superscript = document.createElement("sup");
superscript.text = 'test';

textNode.appendChild( superscript );

</script>
```

Firefox gives the error

> uncaught exception: Node cannot be
>   inserted at the specified point in the
>   hierarchy
>   (NS_ERROR_DOM_HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR)

Comment: The conclusion conflicts with code in <Web.Design.with.JavaScript.and.the.Document.Object.Model.2005>

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referencing in your comment, but I added a snippet to backup my statement.

Comment: Well, IE's javascript errors are rarely useful, and this case is no exception. "Unexpected call to method or property access".  It does report the correct line number, though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so; I'm fairly certain that something like

```
<div>this is some <a href="...">text</a> with an element inside it.</div>
```

ends up being:

```
<div>
    <textnode/>
    <a>
        <textnode/>
    </a>
    <textnode/>
</div>
```

I don't believe textNodes can have children.

If I had to guess, I'd think that the result of adding a child node to a text node would be to add the element to the text node's parent instead, but I've not tested that at all.

Comment: Correct.  The element is a sibling of the text nodes, not a child.

Comment: then the above code is wrong?it's in the book <Web.Design.with.JavaScript.and.the.Document.Object.Model.2005>

Comment: I added a bit at the end of my answer -- I don't think it's wrong, I think the DOM will do the right thing there.

Comment: You mean appending a child to a textNode is the same as appending it to its parent?

Comment: That would be my *guess*. However, it wouldn't be the first time some code got printed in a book despite being completely wrong. :)

Comment: It's a pity there is no simple way to prove whether it's wrong or right.

Comment: Oh,I've misunderstood the author,there is "quotes[i].getElementsByTagName('*');" which ensured "elem" is an elementNode!

Comment: But this question still deserves a answer,i think:)

Answer (score 0):

No. Elements may contain attributes, other elements, or text.