# JavaScript: Add elements in textNode

Tags: javascript, html, replace, textnode

I want to add an element to a textNode. For example: I have a function that search for a string within element's textNode. When I find it, I want to replace with a HTML element. Is there some standard for that?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you / do you want to use jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. But BTW, show your solution to the other guys...

Comment: You already have the function to search for the string, or you're asking about that, too?

Answer (score 20):

You can't just replace the string, you'll have to replace the entire TextNode element, since [TextNode elements can't contain child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111258/can-a-textnode-have-a-childnode-which-is-an-elementnode) in the DOM.

So, when you find your text node, generate your replacement element, then replace the text node with a function similar to:

```
function ReplaceNode(textNode, eNode) {
    var pNode = textNode.parentNode;
    pNode.replaceChild(textNode, eNode);
}
```

For what it appears you want to do, you will have to break apart the current Text Node into two new Text Nodes and a new HTML element.  Here's some sample code to point you hopefully in the right direction:

```
function DecorateText(str) {
    var e = document.createElement("span");
    e.style.color = "#ff0000";
    e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return e;
}

function SearchAndReplaceElement(elem) {
    for(var i = elem.childNodes.length; i--;) {
        var childNode = elem.childNodes[i];
        if(childNode.nodeType == 3) { // 3 => a Text Node
            var strSrc = childNode.nodeValue; // for Text Nodes, the nodeValue property contains the text
            var strSearch = "Special String";
            var pos = strSrc.indexOf(strSearch);

            if(pos >= 0) {
                var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                if(pos > 0)
                    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(strSrc.substr(0, pos)));

                fragment.appendChild(DecorateText(strSearch));

                if((pos + strSearch.length + 1) < strSrc.length)
                    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(strSrc.substr(pos + strSearch.length + 1)));

                elem.replaceChild(fragment, childNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe jQuery would have made this easier, but it's good to understand why all of this stuff works the way it does.

Comment: Do you have any examples? Thank you.