# Issue with replacing color of word occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I am trying to replace the font color of "bad" throughout an HTML page to red but there are two main issues, firstly it repeats the entire sentence before replacement and I do not want that and also the bad in "badly" was also replaced but I just want only the font in the word "bad" replaced. How do I go about this? Here is my code

```js
 window.onload = function() {
   var text = document.getElementById("content");
   var str = text.innerHTML,
     reg = /red/ig;

   var toStr = String(reg);
   var color = (toStr.replace('\/g', '|')).substring(1);

   var colors = color.replace("|");

   if (colors.indexOf("red") > -1) {
     str = str.replace(/bad/g, '<span style="color:red;">bad</span>');
   }


   document.getElementById("updated").innerHTML = str;
 }
```

```html
<div id="content">are they good or bad, tell me how badly it is if bad.</div>
<div id="updated"></div>
```

Comment: use `\b` or whatever it is to put "word boundaries" around "red". that'd prevent `redemption` from getting mangled.

Comment: You might want to break up the contents of the div into an array of words, then process each word individually. You should be able to do this like: var ih = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;var words = ih.split(/\b/g);for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){if(words[i] == 'bad'){...

Comment: \b helped with the boundary on "bad" but I still haven't found solution to the repetition. @MarcB

Comment: "_firstly it repeats the entire sentence before replacement and I do not want that_"... what does that even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **\b** (a word boundary token) as said by [raphael75](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827764/raphael75)
`str = str.replace(/\b(bad)\b/gi, '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>');`

also, I:

- added the **i** modifier, for it to be case insensitive (capture Bad, BAD, bad)
- encapsulated (bad) in the regEx to call again with $1, this keeps the case (if capitalized Bad, stays Bad)

  ```js
  var str = "bad incredibad badly Bad, testing bad, bad. bad";
  str = str.replace(/\b(bad)\b/gi, '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>');
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = str;
  ```

  ```html
  <p></p>
  ```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a go-to place for JavaScript RegEx

Answer (score 0):

To replace text in HTML documents, it is a good idea to traverse the DOM tree and replace the content of text nodes where needed.

To match complete words only ("bad" but not "badly"), use regex with [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`.

The following implementation performs depth-first DOM tree traversal and replaces text nodes containing the word "bad" with text nodes for both the text before and after that word as well as a `<span style="color: red">bad</span>` in place of "bad":

```js
var walk = (node, func) => {
  var children = node.childNodes;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    walk(children[i], func);
  }
  func(node);
};

var highlight = (text, color) => {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.color = color;
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return span;
};

var root = document.getElementById("content");

walk(root, (node) => {
  if (node.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) return;
  var texts = node.data.split(/\bbad\b/),
      length = texts.length;
  if (length > 1) {
    var fragment = texts.reduce((fragment, text, i) => {
      fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
      if (i < length - 1) fragment.appendChild(highlight("bad", "red"));
      return fragment;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, node);            
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="content">are they good or bad, tell me how badly it is <bad>bad bad bad</bad> if bad.</div>
```

See also: [JavaScript: Add elements in textNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963872/javascript-add-elements-in-textnode)